# A tag for infinite subjects?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be appropriate to create a tag for questions dealing with infinity, infinitesimals, or related subjects?

Comment: I suppose a tag for this would be appropriate, given that infinity is one of the more difficult concepts to understand.  What name do you propose for the tag?

Comment: I note that an [tag:infinitesimals] tag already exists.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche, I waited for half a day and when there was no response I figured this particular meta site is not very active.  Since, in particular, nobody expressed opposition to the idea. I created the tag yesterday.

Comment: Are you saying you were the one to create the [tag:infinitesimals] tag?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche, yes.  Is that alright?

Comment: Having the tag(s)  is alright. I would however appreciate if there was not too much promotional content (some is fine, after all a point of the site is to exchange what are perceived as best practices; just don't go overboard :-)).

Comment: @quid, thanks, I knew I could count on your support.

Comment: Yes, I think it is alright to create this tag.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche, thanks. Since my edits around the [tag:infinitesimals] tag were found a bit controversial, could you create the [tag:infinity] tag? I think it would also be useful and make certain searches easier.

Comment: It is not possible to create a tag in abstract. Tags are just created by being applied to a question. If you could propose a question that would be good for [tag:infinity] I'll be happy to put it there. Or maybe I misunderstood your request. If you want the infinitesimals tag renamed, I can do this.

Comment: See e.g. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/689/1385 @quid

Comment: I put the requested tag on this question.

Comment: Thanks. Does https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1497/1385 seem appropriate for the same tag? @quid

Comment: Yes, this could be a good question too. I do not apply it right away, since I do not want to bring up too many old question to the frontpage at the same time. The site is quite low volume, so this  is much more of an issue than say on math.se. I think you could just suggest the edit at some point in time.